# How to plot Learning Rate and Epoch when training a CNN?

Tags: r, machine-learning, keras, conv-neural-network

I am trying to use a cosine-based decay schedule to improve the accuracy of my CNN. I want to visually see the changes that are made to the model's learning rate by this schedule throughout the training.

How can I plot the learning rate curve with the learning rate on the y-axis and the step on the x-axis in R? An example curve from another source is featured here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/q7d1q.png

See Code Below:

```
# 1. Learning Rate Settings
learning_rate_schedule_cosine_decay(initial_learning_rate = 0, decay_steps = 1000, alpha = 0, name = 'Cosine Decay') 
lr_decayed_fn <- learning_rate_schedule_cosine_decay(initial_learning_rate = 0.0001, decay_steps = 1000)

# 2. Model Compilation
model <- keras_model_sequential()
model%>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = c(3,3), activation = 'relu', input_shape = c(256, 256, 3))%>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 32, kernel_size = c(3,3), activation = 'relu')%>%
  layer_max_pooling_2d(pool_size = c(2,2))%>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.25)%>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 64, kernel_size = c(3,3), activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_conv_2d(filters = 64, kernel_size = c(3,3), activation = 'relu') %>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.25) %>%
  layer_flatten()%>%
  layer_dense(units = 256, activation = 'relu')%>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.25)%>%
  layer_dense(units = 128, activation = 'relu')%>%
  layer_dropout(rate = 0.25)%>%
  layer_dense(units = 4, activation = 'softmax')%>%
  compile(loss = 'categorical_crossentropy',
          optimizer = optimizer_adam(lr = lr_decayed_fn, name = 'Adam'),
          metrics = c('accuracy'))
summary(model)


# Fit Model
history <- model%>%
  fit(trainx,
      trainLabels,
      epochs = 30,
      batch_size = 32,
      validation_split = 0.2)
plot(history)
```